# VSCode Extension: How to disable tree items when enablement clause on linked command is false

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building a VSCode extension and currently creating a new custom view that will have tree items linked to commands.

The goal is to greyout/disable certain tree items when the `enablement` property on a command evaluates to <del>true</del> false.

This works fine when the commands that are added as menu items to the view and will grey out the icon & will not be able to be clicked, however, I would have expected the same result to happen with the items in the tree.

[image: Example of VSCode Tree Items not disabling for commands]

My package.json schema looks like so:

```
{
    "contributes": {        
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "extension.iis-express.start",
                "title": "Start Website",
                "category": "IIS Express",
                "enablement": "iisexpress:siterunning != true && isWindows",
                "icon": "$(play)"
            },
            {
                "command": "extension.iis-express.stop",
                "title": "Stop Website",
                "category": "IIS Express",
                "enablement": "iisexpress:siterunning && isWindows",
                "icon": "$(debug-stop)"
            },
            {
                "command": "extension.iis-express.restart",
                "title": "Restart Website",
                "category": "IIS Express",
                "enablement": "iisexpress:siterunning && isWindows",
                "icon": "$(refresh)"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "commandPalette": [
                {
                    "command": "extension.iis-express.start",
                    "when": "iisexpress:siterunning != true && isWindows"
                },
                {
                    "command": "extension.iis-express.stop",
                    "when": "iisexpress:siterunning && isWindows"
                },
                {
                    "command": "extension.iis-express.restart",
                    "when": "iisexpress:siterunning && isWindows"
                }
            ],
            "view/title": [
                {
                    "command": "extension.iis-express.start",
                    "group": "navigation@10"
                },
                {
                    "command": "extension.iis-express.restart",
                    "group": "navigation@11"
                },
                {
                    "command": "extension.iis-express.stop",
                    "group": "navigation@12"
                }
            ]
        },
        "views": {
            "explorer": [
                {
                    "id": "iisexpress.controls",
                    "contextualTitle": "IIS Express",
                    "name": "IIS Express",
                    "when": "isWindows"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My tree menu items are added to the view in the following way

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export class ControlsTreeProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<ControlsTreeItem> {


    onDidChangeTreeData?: vscode.Event<void | ControlsTreeItem | null | undefined> | undefined;

    getTreeItem(element: ControlsTreeItem): vscode.TreeItem | Thenable<vscode.TreeItem> {
        return element;
    }

    getChildren(element?: ControlsTreeItem | undefined): vscode.ProviderResult<ControlsTreeItem[]> {
        if(element === undefined){
            const items = new Array<ControlsTreeItem>();
            items.push(
                {
                    label: 'Start Website',
                    iconPath: new vscode.ThemeIcon("play"),
                    collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None,
                    command: {
                        title: 'Start Website',
                        command: "extension.iis-express.start"
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Restart Website',
                    iconPath: new vscode.ThemeIcon("refresh"),
                    collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None,
                    command: {
                        title: 'Restart Website',
                        command: "extension.iis-express.restart"
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Stop Website',
                    iconPath: new vscode.ThemeIcon("debug-stop"),
                    collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None,
                    command: {
                        title: 'Stop Website',
                        command: "extension.iis-express.stop"
                    }
                });

            return items;
        }

        return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
}

export class ControlsTreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {}
```

In the main extension.ts entrypoint

```js
// Register tree provider to put our custom commands into the tree
// Start, Stop, Restart, Support etc...
const controlsTreeProvider = new ControlsTreeProvider();
vscode.window.registerTreeDataProvider('iisexpress.controls', controlsTreeProvider);
```

So the question is, can this be done at all?

Thanks,
Warren :)

Comment: I think you mean: evaluates to **false**

Comment: Currently you can't disable a `TreeItem`. And the command of a `TreeItem` is a `Command` object and for a menu it is a string. You can add a feature request.

Comment: OK thanks...
I will go off & convert this into a feature request report on the VSCode GitHub repo

Comment: For anyone following along - GitHub issue is created here
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102794

Comment: in the question title: `disablement` is not a property. `enablement` and `false`