# VSCode enable/disable commands in custom TreeView based on properties of node/item

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on a custom VSCode extension that fetches data from a remote API and presents the data within a custom tree-view. The treeview itself allows to interact with the API and i.e. filter results based on some predefined criteria such as a search term or whether or not the response has some files attached to it, adding new nodes to or removing or updating existing nodes in the tree dynamically.

For simplicity reasons I created an own [Github project](https://github.com/RovoMe/vscode-treeview-sample) to just focus on the basic setup and configuration of a tree that more or less operates on some fake API methods but provides similar capabilities typical CRUD APIs provide.

[image]

<sub><sup>GIF was resized to fit the 2MB limit and thus produces ugly artifacts</sup></sub>

While showing action-icons for commands on a `TreeView`, defined by a custom `TreeDataProvider`, and on a `TreeItem` are fairly straight forward by defining something like:

```json
...
{
  "contributes":
      "commands": [
          {
              "command": "extension.myTreeView.filter",
              "title": "Filter",
              "icon": "$(filter)",
              "when": "view == extension.myTreeView"
          },
          {
              "command": "extension.myTreeView.resetFilter",
              "title": "Reset Filter",
              "shortTitle": "Reset",
              "icon": "$(close)",
              "enablement": "view == extension.myTreeView && extension.myTreeView.hasFilter",
              "when": "view == extension.myTreeView && extension.myTreeView.hasFilter"
          },
          {
              "command": "extension.myTreeView.delete",
              "title": "Delete Item",
              "shortTitle": "Delete",
              "icon": "$(trash)",
              "when": "view == extension.myTreeView && viewItem == archive"
          }
          ...
      ],
      "menus": {
          "view/title": [
              {
                  "command": "extension.myTreeView.filter",
                  "when": "view == extension.myTreeView"
                  "group": "navigation@1"
              },
              {
                  "command": "extension.myTreeView.resetFilter",
                  "when": "view == extension.myTreeView",
                  "group": "navigation@2"
              },
              ...   
          ],
          "view/item/context": [
              ...
              {
                  "command": "extension.myTreeView.delete",
                  "when": "view == extension.myTreeView && viewItem == archive",
                  "group": "inline@3"
              }
          ]
      }
},
...
```

in the `package.json` file, I somehow struggle to add enabling conditions to commands targeting a particular item itself. I.e. the tree allows the download of some files contained in (or attached to) the item represented by the node. Such nodes may or may not have files attached to them and thus enabling the download action only makes sense for nodes that at least have a file to download. While generally downloading that content or rendering the button for triggering the download action isn't the issue, the enabling option for that command is where I am a bit clueless.

I temporarily "solved" that issue by defining different kinds of `contextValue`'s for such tree nodes, one for an archive with and one without files to download. While this in general seems to solve that issue, it a) doesn't feel proper and b) leads to downstream problems. Imagine that archives can be locked preventing users who do not belong to the group the archive was locked for the actual download. This is just a fictional case here but should illustrate that you might end up with a combination of property fields within that `contextValue` variable that you more or less need to parse in that enable statement. And each further possible context value option must be carried around through the whole `commands` and `menus` definitions like this:

```json
...
{
    "command": "extension.myTreeView.delete",
    "when": "view == extension.myTreeView && viewItem == archive || viewItem == archiveWithFiles || viewItem == ...",
    "group": "inline@2"
},
...
```

In general, [custom context variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#add-a-custom-when-clause-context), such as `hasFilter` in the sample command configuration shown above, which can be used in the `enablement` and `when` clauses, can be used to show/hide or enable/disable certain commands but these seem to work only on the whole tree itself and not a particular tree item. I.e. the sample application uses the following code to enable/disable the `resetFilter` command based on whether a filter is defined or not:

```js
    ...

    public async updateFilter(filter: Filter): Promise<void> {
        this.filter = filter;

        await commands.executeCommand("setContext", TestTreeDataProvider.CONTEXT_HAS_FILTER, true);
        this.items = [];
        this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
    }

    private async resetFilter(): Promise<void> {
        this.filter = undefined;
        await commands.executeCommand("setContext", TestTreeDataProvider.CONTEXT_HAS_FILTER, false);
        this.items = [];
        this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
    }
```

This works as this is more or less a global action on the tree itself and has a single source of property it reacts to. But such context values may only have base types assigned to them or objects where only the keys (a.k.a. property names) of that objects are checked for their availability in `in` clauses. I could potentially create custom context variables per tree item generated but then I need some form of addressing mechanism as each of the context value names must be different or else they are overwritten by the context value of the next node. And as the tree can hold plenty of nodes I feel adding a context value per node is also not very performant then. In the end what seems to be missing here is a way to define a function as context value that allows the current node (either the TreeItem or the actual object the node is referring to) as input and needs to return one of the base types as output, i.e. `true` or `false` to determine whether that item should be enabled or not.

While [this SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955371/vscode-extension-how-to-disable-tree-items-when-enablement-clause-on-linked-com) may sound similar, it actually asks for disabling the whole tree item node when I just want the command that can be performed on that tree item to enable/disabled based on some  tree item's current property value. Some styling of `TreeItem`s based on their context can be done via `FileDecorationProvider`'s. That question also is a result of a bug inside VSCode that doesn't seem to force a rerender on any changes done to the enablement guards.

I feel that there must be an easier solution on this matter and that's why I ask here. In short, how can a command be enabled/disabled in Visual Studio Code based on the current tree items' context (either properties held by or functions executed on that node)?

Comment: if the Tree is not working what you want you can implement it all to your liking by using a `WebviewView`

Comment: @rioV8 The tree itself is working. I am only interested in how to enable/disable commands based on some tree item state (properties or functions performed on that item). If going for a Webview I basically need to reimplement the whole tree functionality here, which is not what I want or have the time for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now put a type description as the context value of the TreeItem.

Why not put the allowed operations also in the context value:

```
archive_Del
archive_Read_Update
```

Then use this in the `when` clause

```
{
    "command": "extension.myTreeView.delete",
    "when": "view == extension.myTreeView && viewItem =~ /^.*_Del.*$/",
    "group": "inline@2"
}

{
    "command": "extension.myTreeView.read",
    "when": "view == extension.myTreeView && viewItem =~ /^.*_Read.*$/",
    "group": "inline@2"
}
```

Comment: I mentioned that this works and is currently also the way I'm basically doing it but it doesn't feel proper to me nor does it allow for more dynamic enablements. I.e. What if I only want to enable a command if an item property is above a certain threshold and this threshold can be dynamically defined. Sure, I can "generate" a `contextValue` that is specifically created for certain options, but this sounds like a misuse of the `contextValue` "string"

Comment: @RomanVottner The logic if a particular command is allowed is moved to the creation of the TreeItem, you don't have to add tons of context values to the `when` clause, `archiveType1`, `archiveType2`, They are all `archive` and in the extension you determine if this TreeItem is allowed to be Updated, Deleted, HasFileToDownload and these properties encoded in the `viewItem` context value, you can always recreate parts of the Tree if needed, what is wrong in showing a button but in the code you do nothing because for some reason the delete is not allowed anymore, maybe show a message

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I understood your last sentence. The code in this post was just a sample to demonstrate how a general definition would look like. The sample code I put up on [Github](https://github.com/RovoMe/vscode-treeview-sample/blob/master/package.json#L55) does contain the "specific" type  query for archives with files as well, eventhough your syntax is probably more clear and avoids a lot of repetition.